# Card game - probability

Tags: probability, reference-request, self-learning, card-games

In the card game ($32$ cards, $3$ players receive $10$ cards each, $2$ remain),

$A$ = "The remaining ones contain $2$ aces"
$K$ = "I get at least one king". 
In total there are $4$ aces and $4$ kings.

- What is the probability of $P(K)$?
- What is the probability of
  $P(K|A)$?

apart from "Conditional Probability", may I know which topics or formulas should I study and use to solve the questions?

Thanks for the help and kindness!

Comment: You should study combinatorics. In basics combinatorics there are many different topics and formulas that can help you solve problems like this one.

Comment: I feel like I saw this exact problem a few months ago... In any case this should be a trivial application of the counting principles you had used before and/or hypergeometric probability distributions as well as the definition of conditional probability.

Comment: The probability of at least one king in your hand... reworded for flavor is the same problem as asking for the probability that you draw at least one red ball when drawing ten balls without replacement from a bucket of 32 who had four red balls in it.  That is precisely the type of problem hypergeometric distributions are used for.  To be fair, I had never learned the *name* of the distribution until long after having used it numerous times.  You could just as naturally come upon the formula by counting principles, using binomial coefficients to count.

Comment: For the conditional probability at the end, you could do it directly instead by just pretending the "bucket only had 30 balls to start with."